# InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to HttpClient

Tags: soap, apache-axis

I have generated axis2 client stub using WSDL2Java command and trying to call a third party web service.
I see this error in console:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient cannot be cast to class org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient (org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient and org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @674c583e)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.getHttpClient(AbstractHTTPSender.java:529)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:157)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

We are setting the CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT property like this(Put both lines):

```
     MyStub stub = new MyStub() ; 

        stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, customHttpClient);
            stub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext()
                    .setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, customHttpClient);
```

But somehow AbstractHttpSender.getHttpClient is unable to get our HttpCLient.
This is the line in AbstractHttpSender class where ClassCastException is thrown:-

```
  HttpClient httpClient = (HttpClient) msgContext.getProperty(
                HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT);
```

Do I need to pass anything in MyStub() constructor to make sure that HttpClient is set properly in MessageContext?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I can see the issue. HttpClient above is org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient rather than org.apache.http.client.HttpClient (as I was thinking earlier).
Now how do I resolve it? Is there a way for axis2 client stub to not go to AbstractHttpSender and go to a class that uses org.apache.http.client.HttpClient?